# CKFinder3 dynamically change folder path

Tags: php, ckeditor, ckfinder

Is there anyway to change the baseUrl of CKFinder dynamically?

I need to use this kind of path: `/websitebuilder/www/user_images/$id/`. I used google to find some answer, but I didn't manage to make it works.

Can someone please give me any hint how should I do that?

I know that in config.php you change the **baseUrl** param, but how to make it dinamically?

Answer (score 2):

1 create new middleware:

php artisan make:middleware DynamicCkfinderConfig

with this code in the handel function :
not forget to 'use Auth' in the top of file;

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if (auth()->check()) {

            config([
                'ckfinder.backends.default' => [
                    'name' => 'default',
                    'adapter' => 'local',
                    'baseUrl' => '/user-' . md5(Auth::user()->id) . '/',
                    'root' => public_path('/user-' . md5(Auth::user()->id) . '/'),
                    'chmodFiles' => 0777,
                    'chmodFolders' => 0755,
                    'filesystemEncoding' => 'UTF-8'
                ]
            ]);
        
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

2 add the middleware in the kernel.php file

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'ckfinderConfig' => \App\Http\Middleware\DynamicCkfinderConfig::class,
    ];
```

3 use the middleware in the ckfinder connector route

```
Route::any('/ckfinder/connector', [CKFinderController::class, 'requestAction'])
    ->name('ckfinder_connector')->middleware(['ckfinderConfig']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use the example for [different folder per instance CKFinder 3 HOWTO](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckfinder/ckfinder3-php/howto.html#howto_folder_instance).

Basically you should update you `config.php` to something like this:

```php
$id = getID();

$config['backends'][] = array(
    'name'    => 'default',
    'adapter' => 'local',
    'baseUrl' => 'http://example.com/ckfinder/userfiles/' . $id,
    'root'    => '/path/to/ckfinder/userfiles/' . $id
);
```

Comment: I tried it, but I am using a framework, and the CKFinder is not in the app. So I wasn't able to get the id. Anyway, I solved it by setting the CKEditor param: `filebrowserImageBrowseUrl`

Comment: Greetings,

I'm currently working on a project where we're using various instances of the ckeditor5 with the ckfinder php connector and we need a dynamic change of baseUrl per instance..  I've tried to do it based on this approach and the HOWTO example you refer to, but I'm unable to receive the id param in the config.php file. Could you provide some more details into how you've constructed the getID() method or how to receive the id in the config.php file ? Thanks.

Comment: Please check the linked documentation page as it has more comprehensive examples.